# NFS local user mapping works, but not with sudo

Tags: nfs, sudo, nfs4

I want to use an NFS share for backing up. I have created a local user on the client with a specific uid/gid combination that works for writing files to the NFS share. So far so good.

However, I need `sudo` to read all users' home directories on the local box for backup purposes. But when I do that, the uid/gid is set to 0 and I can't access the NFS share anymore. How do I get around this without access to the server or changing permissions on local files?

Comment: You can't.  You will have to change your backup strategy (eg, to many small backups each running as an individual user).

Comment: Is there not even a way with some `idmapd` cleverness?

Comment: you can export with no_root_squash and later on change files ownership to desired uid/gid

Comment: That requires access to the server, to change `/etc/exports`.  The question says the OP has no such access.

Comment: You could use `tar` to preserve file ownership and other metadata and copy or pipe the tarfile to a process running as an ordinary user to store it on the NFS server.